# How do I get the foursquare venue ID from the new pretty url

Tags: foursquare

The new venue urls are prettier but the ID isn't there and there is no mechanism to look up the ID from the pretty url.

For example, this particular url:
https://foursquare.com/felice_83

How can I look up the venueID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the righthand sidebar, there is a link to Claim the location. In the URL for that claim link, the "vid" parameter is the venue ID.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore - as they changed the page details.

Answer (score 1):

When searching a Place on [foursquare.com](https://foursquare.com), or expanding a `4sq.com` short link, the ID will be appended automatically to the pretty URL, e.g.

```
https://foursquare.com/v/sim-lim-square/4b058815f964a520aab022e3
```

Where `4b058815f964a520aab022e3` is the Venue ID. This will save you time on manual lookups compared to reverse engineering the `vid` query string param from the "[Claim it now.](https://foursquare.com/venue/claim?vid=4b058815f964a520aab022e3)" links.

Comment: Do you have happen to know how to do the opposite (getting the page from the ID)?

Comment: Hi @Jean-FrancoisT I'm sorry I stopped sending my data to 4sq in early 2018 so I'm not sure personally. Please do let us know if you figure it out. 

Comment: I stopped using 4sq not long after :) but I'm using an app that uses it.
I will probably create a new question in SO and let you know ;)